# Travel.SE meetup: London, Oct 11

Tags: discussion, community

Anyone in the London, UK area is invited to the Parcel Yard Pub, inside the King's Cross station ([info here](https://plus.google.com/105714660704862058155/about)) at 5:30pm, Friday 11th October, 2013.  Walk to platform 9 3/4 (no really!) and the pub is up the steps to your left.

And please join the [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/118962814909394/) to suggest future meetups!

Comment: I suggested creating [a Facebook event](https://www.facebook.com/events/187461341441894/) so that we can contact each other in case we need to. I'm attending! :)

Comment: Certainly not the first, but it's cool that it's happening :) Enjoy it!

Comment: For those of you not sure on the whole "Platform 9 3/4 at Kings Cross Station" thing, [this answer has a photo of it](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9659/26) to prove I'm not making it up! ;)

Comment: It is customary for mods to buy the first round.. wink @AnkurBanerjee :)

Comment: London?? Why not pick a traveller's destination? d-;

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee has to travel like an hour to get there ;)

Comment: Meetup is in about 18 hours, don't forget! :)

Comment: Thanks for organising the evening Jonathan + Julie, was great fun to meet everyone! :)

Comment: Who was all there??

Comment: Me, Julie (a friend of mine), Nick, Stuart, and Ankur (after I left). I think that's all.

Comment: I reckon that's still the biggest one we've had - great effort! :)